# Validating docker v0.8 on OS X, boot2docker ssh hangs, docker version generates EOF

Tags: validation, installation, osx-mavericks, docker

On OSX 10.9 with Virtual Box 4.3.6 and using boot2docker.

```
1) ./boot2docker ssh
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I don't always see the last line. The documentation leads me to believe that this might be a key problem, but attempts to run ssh-keygen to remove keys on the OSX hosts run afoul of a message that the known_hosts file is not valid (though it exists and has worked for other purposes). I never see the login.

2) I see some strange behavior some of which keep me from getting further installing an updated Ubuntu, etc.

```
bin:98 $ ./docker version 
Client version: 0.8.0 Go version (client): go1.2 
Git commit (client): cc3a8c8 
2014/02/06 09:47:39 unexpected EOF
```

It would seem that at least the version option has a bug.

Any suggestions as to what either I might have done wrong or whether I need to await a fix?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: [boot2docker#149](https://github.com/steeve/boot2docker/issues/149)

My problem is the boot2docker images didn't boot successfully, and I tried downloading boot2docker.iso manually from the "[Release Page](https://github.com/steeve/boot2docker/releases)", it works.

Comment: Confirmed. It's unexpected that one has to manually insert the iso file into the ~/boot2docker/ subdirectory, but if one does things do work as expected.